# How to make a field unique across two models in Django without inheritance?

Tags: python, django, orm, crud

I have following 2 models, Admin and Employee:

```
class Admin(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    department  = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

What I want is to ensure that the field `email` is unique across both the models i.e. no two admins can have the same `email` AND no two employees can have the same `email` AND no admin and employee have the same `email`.

I created a base class `CustomUser` and inherited it to both `Employee` and `Admin` class:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)

  

class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_lengt=30)
    email = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

class Admin(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_lengt=30)
    email = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

What I want to know is, is there any other way of ensuring this kind of cross-model uniqueness that wouldn't require me to create a separate Abstract class?

Comment: It looks a bit odd to make two models in the first place.

Comment: Yes it will work, but your approach could be improved. Perhaps using a base class for both employee and admin would be better, with unique email, and name, city fields, and inherit them for both, and then declare extra fields as required.
Also if insists no inheritance or separate model required, you can make email unique for one model, and update the save function of the other model to check his existence before saving record, but again that wont be a good approach.